# RStudio, Rcpp package

Tags: rstudio, rcpp

I am trying to import csv file in Rstudio bu it is showing that Rcpp packege is not installed n when i tried it to install using install.packages("Rcpp") error getting as:In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1

Comment: Why do you need Rcpp to import a csv?

Comment: `points <- read.csv(file="points-Germany.csv",head=TRUE,sep=";")`